# Cannot call a function from a child type from a constructor

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to call a function from a child type from a constructor? Please take a look at the example

```
class Dog(animalType: DogType) : Animal(animalType) {
    fun doSomething() {
        animalType.runDogTypeFunction() // error but animalType is always DogType
    }
}

abstract class Animal(val animalType: AnimalType)
interface AnimalType

enum class DogType() : AnimalType {
    DOG1, DOG2;
    fun runDogTypeFunction() {}
}

enum class CatType() : AnimalType {
    CAT1, CAT2;
    fun runCatTypeFunction() {}
}
```

animalType is const (val) so it always is DogType. I do not understand why I cannot call a method from the DogType class.
I tried to override val but I received NPE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your property is declared in the base Animal class (as AnimalType). The constructor param in Dog doesn't exist by the time you call doSomething.

You could try something like this:

```
abstract class Animal<T: AnimalType>(val animalType: T)

class Dog(animalType: DogType) : Animal<DogType>(animalType) {
    fun doSomething() {
        animalType.runDogTypeFunction()
    }
}
```